# RN view over android native activity

Tags: android, react-native, view, bridge

I have a React Native app where I used an Android activity (thanks to a bridge). I would like to display some javascript text over this activity, but I don't have any solution. It seems like the android activity isn't considered as a React view, so I cannot manipulate it.

If someone could help me with my little problem, maybe I don't understand a React Native feature or something.

Thanks !